# How do I shorten an array in Perl 6?

Tags: arrays, raku

How could I cut off an array or an array-reference in Perl 6?

In Perl 5, I can do this:

```
my $d = [0 .. 9];
$#$d = 4;
```

In Perl 6, I get an error if I try this:

```
my $d = [0 .. 9];
$d.end = 4; # Cannot modify an immutable Int
```

This works, but it looks less beautiful than the Perl 5 way and may be expensive:

```
 $d.=splice(0, 5);
```

Comment: In Perl5, I'd use `splice(@a, 5);` as it wouldn't stretch the array when there are less than 5 elements. (It also allows you to use the number of elements desired instead of one less. It also avoids the construction and setting of a magical scalar.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a simple way:

```
my $d = [0..9];

$d[5..*] :delete;
```

That is problematic if the array is an infinite one.

`$d.splice(5)` also has the same problem.

Your best bet is likely to be `$d = [ $d[^5] ]` in the average case where you may not know anything about the array, and need a mutable Array.

If you don't need it to be mutable `$d = $d[^5]` which returns a List may be better.

Comment: can you describe what `^5` does?  (particularly if there are < 4 elements to begin with)

Comment: @ysth "The caret is ... a prefix operator for constructing numeric ranges starting from zero". Included this in my answer but I can't really expand on it. If the Range goes beyond the end of the existing list/array it will return extra elements as an `(Any)` type for an `Array` or `(Nil)` for a `List`. You can then assign to that element.  As @ikegami terms it, the array will "stretch". `(Array)`, `(List)`, `(Nil)`, `(Any)` are not equivalent and will behave differently.

Answer (score 6):

[`splice`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Array#routine_splice)  is probably the best choice here, but you can also shorten to five elements using the `^N` range constructor shortcut (I call this the "up until" "operator" but I am sure there is a more correct name since it is a constructor of a [`Range`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Range#Methods)):

```
> my $d = [ 0 .. 9 ];
> $d.elems
> 10
> $d = [ $d[^5] ]
[0 1 2 3 4]
> $d.elems
5
> $d
[0 1 2 3 4]
```

> "The caret is ... a prefix operator for constructing numeric ranges
>   starting from zero". 
>  
>                                                                                     (From the [`Range` documentation](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Range))

One can argue that perl6 is "perl-ish" in the sense it usually has an explicit version of some operation (using a kind of "predictable" syntax - a method, a routine, and `:adverb`, etc.)  that is understandable if you are not familiar with the language, and then a shortcut-ish variant.

I'm not sure which approach (`splice` vs. the shortcut vs. using `:delete` as Brad Gilbert mentions) would have an advantage in speed or memory use. If you run:

```
perl6 --profile -e 'my $d = [ 0 .. 9 ]; $d=[ $d[^5] ]'
perl6 --profile -e 'my $d = [ 0 .. 9 ]; $d.=splice(0, 5);'
```

you can see a slight difference. The difference might be more significant if you compared with a real program and workload.

Comment: `perl -E 'my $d = [ 0 .. 9 ];$#$d = 4;say @$d'` prints `01234` so you have an off by one error in `$d = [ $d[^4] ]`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the `xx` operator:

```
my $d = [0..9];

$d.pop xx 4;  #-> (9 8 7 6)
say $d;       #-> [0 1 2 3 4 5]

$d = [0..9];

$d.shift xx 5 #-> (0 1 2 3 4)
say $d;       #-> [5 6 7 8 9)
```